# I get the page number two places and I don't know why

Tags: latex

I want to have the page number corner of the header, however, in addition I get page number also at the bottom. How can I remove this, without removing the header as I do when I Use \thispagestyle{empty}?

This is my YAML, where I guess most of the commands are irrelevant, however, I include them in case they are:

```
---
title: ""

header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
- \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
- \fancyfoot[LO,LE]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{SDU_BLACK_RGB.png}}

- \usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs,mathtools,tabulary,xcolor}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \let\belowcaptionskip\abovecaptionskip
- \let\oldmidrule\midrule
- \usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=md]{caption}
- \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
- \usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
- \usepackage{ctable}
- \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
- \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
 

output: 
  pdf_document:
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
geometry: "left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm"
```

This produce pages like this one with the page number two places.

[image: Page]

Comment: ask yourself this question: what is the bottom part of the page called?

Comment: The footer. I don't know if your aim is to help or not.

Comment: i am only trying to point you in the direction where the problem appears to be .... it looks like a default footer may be defined somewhere ... maybe the page number is an image, part of the SDU_BLACK_RGB.png

Comment: Well, thank you, it actually helped. I added \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{}, and now the page number in the footer (;-)) is gone.

Answer (score 1):

- If you use `\fancyhf{}` instead of `\fancyhead{}` you can clear both head and foot at once.
- There is an unrelated problem with your loading  of `cleveref`. This is one of the new packages which need to be loaded after `hyperref`. As rmarkdown unhelpfully takes away from you the choice on when to load hyperref, you need to delay `cleveref` with `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}}`
- Don't load the same package multiple times (e.g. `caption`)
- No need to load `graphicx`, `xcolor` and `fontenc`, rmarkdown automatically loads them
- if your latex distribution isn't from the stone age, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. And if your tex distribution is from the stone age, you also don't need, because rmarkdown automatically loads it

---

```
---
title: ""
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
geometry: "left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhf{}
- \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
- \fancyfoot[LO,LE]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}}
- \usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs,mathtools,tabulary}
- \let\belowcaptionskip\abovecaptionskip
- \let\oldmidrule\midrule
- \usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=md]{caption}
- \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
- \usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
- \usepackage{ctable}
- \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
- \AtBeginDocument{\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}}
---

test
```